# Appropriate Non parametric statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing

am in doubt as to type of analysis to employ in my research. My topic is the impact of non interest banks to the growth of small-mediumscale enterprises. The questionnaires were administered only to SMEs who have used the non interest product . information obtainned include the total assets and number of employees before and after the use of the non interest product. The sample size is 20 SMEs.

Comment: The nonparametric test analogous to a paired t-test is the paired rank sum test.  The nonparametric analogue to the two-sample t-test is the Mann Whitney test.  For me, the question isn't clear enough to know if either of these or some other test would be appropriate.

Comment: What is really helpful when asking a question is to include a toy data set resembling your data, explain what each variable is, and be specific as to what question you are trying to answer.

Comment: What is the aim of your analysis? What is exactly your problem in here?

Comment: @Tim...  I am investigating whether or not there is a siginficant between the non-interest banks and the growth of small-medium scale enterprises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple t-test would suffice for showing if the SMEs are the same before and after the use of the banks. Nothing non-parametric about this

Comment: @ sal mangiafico. Am just looking for the most appropriate data analysis technique to solving the problem.. Both assets and number of employees are determinants    of growth in a enterprise..logically an increase in assets and number of employees will signify growth while a decrease   will show other wise.  Using non interest product has it own benefit such as access to loans Without interest pay back compared  to the conventional Banking system. I hope you understand better